# Android Geofence Entry Transition Event Triggered even when Not Inside the Geofence

Tags: android, android-geofence

I have created a geofence with 1 km radius at a distance of 5 km from my current location. As soon as that geofence is created, I receive an entry trigger. Why is it so? How can I ensure that geofences trigger only when I enter/dwell in them? I followed the official tutorial as given [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

Comment: What are you setting as the initial trigger?

Comment: According to the docs you linked, you need to set `builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);` so it will only initially trigger on enter.

Comment: I've set it as setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)...Still giving me wrong callbacks

Comment: @DeeV
According to the docs, 

_"Specifying INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER tells Location services that GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER should be triggered if the the device is already inside the geofence."_

However, my device is 4 km away from the entry point of the geofence for which I'm receiving the entry trigger

Comment: Right.  I don't know the real issue which is why I did post as an answer. You should not be getting a trigger if that is what is set. I don't have much experience with Geofencing. The last question is are you sure the event your getting is an  `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER` event and not an `Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT` event? I believe both events will always trigger and you have to filter them yourself.

Comment: @DeeV : I apologise for the late reply. Yes, I set a debug point and observed that `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER` event is triggered explicitly. I understand that you haven't had much to do with geofences but any help from anyone you know who has dabbled with geofences in Android will be really appreciated. Thanks a lot :)